# When returning back to a screen with UIpageviewcontroller , view loaded in pagecontroller does not refresh

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a rootviewContoller with UIPageviewController in which two viewcontrollers, V1 and V2 are loaded at a time.
I have added the following code in viewwillapear of the rootviewcontroller.

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[self.pageViewControllers[self.pageControl.currentPage]]
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:NO
                                     completion:NULL];
```

When the rootviewcontroller is laoded for the first time, control goes to viewwillAppear of v1 or v2(whichever view loaded) and refreshes the view.
However when returning back to this screen(say after popviewcontroller) the view loaded in pagecontroller does not refresh. The viewWillappear of the view loaded in pageviewcontroller is not called at all.

This works fine on iPhone 5. But not in iPhone < 5.

Thanks in advance.